# Number field is having exponential values in while wrting data in CSV file in java

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures

While retrieving data form Stored procedure value is displaying as expected. But when writing data in CSV file using java value storing as exponential value as

- While running  SP value look like : 1979903471947
- But in Generated like :1.9799E+12 (some thing like that)

  ```
  public void writeCsvFile(String fileName) {
      StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("DTATA_FILE");
      query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(O_ERRNO_IN, Integer.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
      query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(CURSOR, Class.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);
      query.execute();

      List<Object[]> rows = query.getResultList();
      try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName)) {
          fileWriter.append(FILE_HEADER);
          fileWriter.append(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);

          for (Object[] row : rows) {

              getFileWriter(fileWriter, row);

          }
          logger.info("CSV file was created successfully !!!");
      } catch (Exception e) {
          logger.fatal("Error in CsvFileWriter !!!", e);
      }
  }

  private void getFileWriter(FileWriter fileWriter, Object[] row) throws IOException {
      for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
          fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(Objects.toString(row[i], "")));
          fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
      }
      fileWriter.append(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);
  }
  ```

IN SP:

```
to_char(am.dti_number)
```

`to_char` is mandatory in Stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Format the number like this:

```
 NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("en", "US"));
 String val = nf.format(n);
```

You might need to tweak the NumberFormat to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Same result got by using toPlainString()

```
private void getFileWriter(FileWriter fileWriter, Object[] row) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
        if (i == 2) {

            BigDecimal bg;

            String str = row[i].toString();
            String s;
            bg = new BigDecimal(str);

            s = bg.toPlainString();

            fileWriter.write(s);
            fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);

        } else {
            fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(Objects.toString(row[i], "")));
            fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
        }
    }
    fileWriter.append(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);
}
```

Comment: This you should add as an edit to your question, not as an answer (because it isn't). However, you haven't really changed anything: `String str = row[i].toString()` is no different from your original `String.valueOf(Objects.toString(row[i], ""))`. May be it's your `entityManager` implementation screws things up.